# Can I Remove Generic Kernel After Installing Ubuntu Studio Wrapper Over Kubuntu?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-studio

I have seen posts online about removing the generic kernel and using only the low-latency one, but this question has a bit of a twist (I think). I'd like some input if anyone has any.

I recently installed the latest Ubuntu Studio LTS, which uses the low-latency kernel. I'm not sure I'm crazy about Ubuntu and might like to switch to what I was using before, which was Kubuntu with the Ubuntu Studio wrapper installed over it. However, with that setup, I end up with the generic kernel that Kubuntu comes with, as well as the low-latency one that the Ubuntu Studio wrapper adds.

I never boot into the generic kernel and not only does it take up space on my hard drive, it also adds clutter to the Grub menu. So my question is: After installing the Ubuntu Studio wrapper over Kubuntu, can I then delete the generic kernel it originally came with AND stop it being re-added/updated? If so, how would I best go about doing that?

(The version of Kubuntu I would be installing would be 22.04, if that helps with an answer. Ubuntu Studio installer I would be adding to it doesn't have a version number listed on the website, but it just adds the low-latency kernel, various software, and probably some dependencies.)

Comment: Latest is not a version of any Ubuntu product. What about later when someone reads this question. Please use a full version number.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the realtime kernel, then it should be safe to remove other kernels, including the generic branch.

You can view installed kernels with this command:

```
dpkg --list *linux-image* | grep "ii"
```

By default, Ubuntu keep the 2 latest kernels of the active branch. You can remove the others, and install them at a later time should you need them again.

Comment: Thanks, Artur. I read somewhere (but can't remember where) of someone removing the generic kernel but the system still being set to update both kernels, so the removed kernel returned after the next update. At the time I read it, the person hadn't found a solution to that issue. Do you know if I would need to take an extra step to prevent this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you can do to prevent that. 

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. :) I'll leave this post open for a while to see what else might come in. I'm not quite ready to try out the new Kubuntu install anyway.